# Why is tab not completeing my code and even not spacing

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My tab key is completely useless it does not complete my code or even not able to indent if I use tab key it shows waiting for other key's response[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bgP6.png)

Thing I have tried:-

I tried change a bit of json but didn't work[My JSON settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrzSq.png)

I have tab competions turned on

Only setting turned on with tab keyword are[Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXkOf.png)

Note:-I have sticky tab stops and tab moves focus turned off so they are not the reason

Comment: 1) don't use images to show us text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541. edit to convert the image to text 2) show us the contents of your keybindings.json file (open it with the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the command palette). You probably bound something to a chord that starts with `tab`. Either that, or an extension added such a binding.

Comment: 3) Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (Tab) was pressed. Waiting for seconde key of chord

It seems like you've started a keyboard shortcut that involves two key presses (a "chord").

You can open your keyboard shortcuts(**Ctrl+K Ctrl+S**)

[image]

Then search for **Tab**. Perhaps you manually set it, or some extension commands started a keyboard shortcut that involves two key presses. You can simply press `Esc` to cancel the one after double-clicking it.

Comment: While this can answer the question, I find this to be an unsatisfying answer, which is why I posted it as a comment before you instead of an answer, choosing instead to wait for more information. Notice how you've pretty much stated exactly what's in my comments